# String.format to output correct syntax in Razor

Tags: c#, string, razor, string.format

```
String.Format("args.{0} = '{1}'", dynaform.RequiredModelName, dynaform.RequiredModel)
```

Expected result:

```
args.myVariable = 'someOtherStuff'
```

Actual result:

```
args.myVariable = &#39;someOtherStuff&#39;
```

---

Second attempt:

```
Html.Raw(String.Format("args.{0} = '{1}'", dynaform.RequiredModelName, dynaform.RequiredModel))
```

Result:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I tell `String.Format` to output `'` as `'` and not as `&#39;`?
This is really frustrating and, since now, I had to avoid String.Format when dealing with `'` or `"`

Comment: `String.Format` is _not_ raping the text like that, `Html.Raw` is.

Comment: The first attempt doesn't use Html.Raw at all, yet it is raping my text.

Comment: Okay, jumping on `Html.Raw` was naive of me, but I still guarantee it's not `String.Format` per se.

Comment: I agree, I also don't think String.Format is the cause. Perhaps I should have pointed out that the call to string.format is wrapped inside <text> tags to force the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [MvcHtmlString.Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

From the specs: `Creates an HTML-encoded string using the specified text value.`

In the posted code:

```
MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("args.{0} = '{1}'", dynaform.RequiredModelName, dynaform.RequiredModel))
```